# How to implement paging for datagrid using LINQ to Entities in wpf?

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, linq-to-entities

I'm new in wpf. My main problem is to understand how DataGrid works with its datacontext. It would help me a lot because I don't know how to make a universal paging usercontrol for all my datagrids in the projects for different database tables. DataGrid converts received DataContext from object to some kind of list. How it is implemented? I tried to do some casting from object to IQueryable`<System.Data.Objects.DataClasses.EntityObject>` to generalize thinig because base class of every entity in the entity model is EntityObject class. But it doesen't work in runtime although I don't receive complains at design time.

Comment: Don't understand you completely. Could you provide a code where you fill DataGrid?

Answer (score 0):

I figured out myself what is all behind datagrid. Even if you didn't understand my question, it's not important anymore and thank you anyway.